# Installing Steam

Tags: 12.04, steam

When I try to install Steam 64bit I get this error:

> ```
> Package dependencies cannot be resolved
>
> This error could be caused by required additional software packages
> which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could
> be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be
> installed at the same time.
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> steam64: Depends: steam (= 1.0.0.27ubuntu1) but it is a virtual package
> ```

Any idea on what to do? I've searched this website and tried most of the answers but none of it worked.

Comment: try to install HOW? using apt, aptitude, the software center?

Comment: Both via the software center and via a .deb file which I downloaded from their site.

If I open the .deb file, I get this error:

Internal Error:
The file “/home/niklas/Hämtningar/steam_latest.deb” could not be opened.

Comment: did you update your software sources? if not just run this command:
"aptitude update && aptitude install steam"

Comment: Nothing happend when I wrote that as a command

Comment: oh you have to run this command as super user, use:
"sudo aptitude update" and after this command use "sudo aptitude  install steam"

Comment: I got a lot of text and a question that asked:

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
I took Y and I got this:
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

Comment: after the update, just try using the software center again, it doesn't make sense to use the command line if you won't understand what it says anyway. To keep your system Safe use the Software Center again! if it still won't let you install steam you have to wait until someone actually knows how to solve that issuse.

Comment: Nothing new, same problem :( oh well :(

Comment: Help us! This is so hard!

Comment: go here, its a recent bug with the latest version of ubuntu, valve is looking into it as of 12 minutes ago. this is a workaround... http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864959809808921128/

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tested yet but there is seems workaround http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/864959809808921128/#c864959809910700746

**NOTE: FOR 12.04.2LTS USERS**

Hey guys, I have a workaround that will let you install the Steam64
install from Ubuntu Software Center.

First, install the 32bit libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

If you're unable to do so due to dependencies, run these commands BEFORE installing `ia32-libs`:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, attempt install `ia32-libs` again. Be patient; the time it took
for me to complete the ia32-libs install took longer than most
installations.

Afterwards, you should be able to install `Steam (64-bit)` through the `Ubuntu Software Center`.  Worked like a charm for me, and I've been
fighting this for several hours.

Good luck!!