# Steam won't Boot (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: boot, steam

### Steam Won't boot

```
Repairing installation, linking /home/brent/.steam/steam to /home/brent /.local/share/Steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/home/brent/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 431: realpath: command not found
/home/brent/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steamui.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version ``GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /home/brent/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/libtier0_s.so)
/home/brent/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steamui.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version ``GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /home/brent/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/libvideo.so)
/home/brent/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version ``GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /home/brent/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam)
/home/brent/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 616: no match: ssfn*
```

This is after trying to Reinstall to try to fix it, Now it won't show anything after attempting to start up.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per the [help/on-topic]. These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

in that situation, the best you can you is to PURGE (delete Steam completely) from your system and then re-install it, here are two links that might be helpful:

- [How do I remove Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217872/how-do-i-remove-steam)
- [Installing Steam](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256560/installing-steam)
- [How do I install Steam 64-bit when package dependencies cannot be resolved?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256271/how-do-i-install-steam-64-bit-when-package-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved)

Hope it helps, good luck!